# "How to display data and change color on a bar chart upon hover?"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a front end for kids to display a chart when certain data is entered to it. 
I want to change the color of the bars on `mouseover`, change the color of the bar and display data related to this bar. 
Need to be done using only **JQuery**, no plugins can be used.

```js
<script id="hover">
    function draw(){
        var n = document.getElementById("num").value;
        var GV = n.split(",");
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var width = 40;
        var X = 50;
        ctx.fillStyle = "#003366";
        for(var i = 0; i<GV.length; i++){
            var h = GV[i];
            ctx.fillRect(X,canvas.height - h, width, h);
            X += width+15;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Firstly add your diagram or whatever code to a `<div>` element, as giving `id` to script tag is bad practice.
- After giving `id='hover'` to your div apply below code and check! I hope this should work.
- Also you can manipulate `.css()` object and append styles as per you requirements.

```
$('#hover').mouseover(function() {
  $(this).css({'font-size': '36px', 'color': 'red', 'background-color': 'blue'});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your tooltip.formatter a little bit so it can show you the the value of point from another series. For example you can write:
Code: Select all

```
  formatter: function() {
    var series = this.series.chart.series;
    if (this.series._i == 0)
      return '<span style="color: white; font-weight: bold;">' + series[1].data[this.x].y + '</span><br/>'
    return '<span style="color: white; font-weight: bold;">' + this.y + '</span><br/>'
  }
```

example how it work:
https://jsfiddle.net/no1eph0b/13/

Have a nice day.